# How do I create boost::posix_time::ptime objects from strings created using QDateTime ISODate format?

Tags: c++, qt, boost

I am migrating my old apps database using my new app. The old app uses QT, the new app does not.

I would like to convert dates that have been stored in the database to boost::posix_time::ptime objects. The dates were stored in the database by converting QDateTime objects to strings, with ISODate format.

So, the source strings have the following format:

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSSZ
```

Is there a simple routine available to generate ptimes from the QDateTime string? I have tried posix_time::from_iso_string, however this fails due to the presence of the '-' delimiters in the date (and likely the ':' delimiter is also a problem).

Comment: You'll probably just need to write your own parser.  Are the strings all strictly formatted this way?  in which case you could use something like sscanf if you can stomach it, or just write a simple parser from scratch.  or use boost regex.  boost spirit is probably overkill and will result in painful compile times, but nice in other respects.

Comment: Alternatively just strip the string of unwanted chars and use from_iso_string.

Comment: How the hell did you get the iso date? I can just find `toString` method on `QDateTime`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a time zone (the Z format flag), it is quite easy. See the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const boost::posix_time::ptime time_with_ms = boost::date_time::parse_delimited_time<boost::posix_time::ptime>("2013-05-31T09:00:00.123", 'T');
    const boost::posix_time::ptime time_without_ms = boost::date_time::parse_delimited_time<boost::posix_time::ptime>("2013-05-31T09:00:00", 'T');
    std::cout << boost::posix_time::to_simple_string(time_with_ms) << std::endl;
    std::cout << boost::posix_time::to_simple_string(time_without_ms) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```